# VB.net How to determine the child form I am passing with value

Tags: vb.net

I have a child form that is passing a vale to another child form.
Child Form1 : TrackerPV
Child Form2 : TrackerNR

here is my code:

```
Dim formChild2 As TrackerPV = DirectCast(Me.MdiParent.MdiChildren(1), TrackerPV)
formChild2.ReceiveValue(cbDecision.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

in this line `Me.MdiParent.MdiChildren(1)` the array 1 is static. what if I opened other child form other than the child forms I am trying to communicate. How I can determine the child form I am sending the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OfType` extension method allows you to filter a list of items by type. That will enable you to get a child form of the specific type you want, e.g.

```vb
Dim formChild2 = MdiParent.MdiChildren.OfType(Of TrackerPV)().FirstOrDefault()

If formChild2 IsNot Nothing Then
    'Use formChild2 here.
End If
```

If you can guarantee that there will always be one child form of that type then you can use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` and omit the null check. If there may be more than one instance of that type then you will need some additional method to distinguish them and access the one you want. You haven't provided enough information for us to know whether that's the case and, if so, how you would go about it.

Comment: Awesome! even though I failed to provide enough information. still you got it right. this solves my problem. Thank You!